# Trying to add a custom context menu item in VSCode that runs commands from an installed extension. Not sure what package.json to edit

Tags: visual-studio-code, contextmenu, vscode-extensions

I installed an extension called [Faker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=deerawan.vscode-faker), and the only way to access its commands are through the Command Palette. So I want to add a new entry to the editor's context menu using `editor/context` and `contributes.menus` [as described here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) - and place all the Faker commands inside the new menu for easy access.

The format goes something like this (non-submenu):

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "menus": {
      "editor/context": [
        {
          "command": "faker.address",
          "group": "faker"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, should I edit the extension's (Faker) `package.json`? Or is there is a global `package.json` that I can edit so I don't have to touch the extension's files?

What's the proper way to go about this?

Thanks much for any help.

Comment: you can try to write your own extension and link the faker commands to menu options, if there is a Faker update you lose your menu items